# Can I take a two pin travel adapter plug in my hand luggage?

Tags: transit, luggage, power, hand-luggage

I'm going to Gran Canaria, and I just wanted to know if it would be safe to take a two pin plug in my hand-luggage, as it might get damaged in my suitcase in transit.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  What's attached to the 2 pin plug?

Comment: Hi thank you, it is a two pin continental travel adapter

Comment: If you are afraid if it getting damaged pack it into layers of clothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine in the hand luggage, I have never heard of having any issues carrying them before so it should be ok.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I bring power adapters in my hand luggage all the time without problems.

Comment: many people do - they can be vital to using the power plugs in the airport, after all.

Answer (score 4):

You could put it into a small cardboard box to prevent damage if you really want to check it. That would prevent it from spearing anything else too. Or wrap it in bubble wrap. Or just shove it inside a shoe etc.

But I typically take a back-pack loaded with all kinds of cables and wires onto every flight. They make me take the laptop out, but that leaves about another dozen devices and a rat's nest of cables, trackball, headphones etc. The nice new color security X-ray units give them a crystal-clear view of what is going on, and I've never had any problems (sometimes they run it back and forth, but seldom even want to look inside).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, i'm just back from NYC trip and i have carried tons of electronics stuff in my hand bag.

Laptop.
Laptop charger.
Tablet.
Tablet charger.
Extra battery.
Extra batter charger.
DSLR camera.
DSLR camera charger.
Bose headphones.
Bose headphones AAA battery.